# Git instaweb httpd configuration to use apache2 on OSX Leopard server

Tags: git, macos, configuration, instaweb

By default git instaweb is expecting lighttpd web server, whereas on OSX Leopard server apache2 is the default one.

Adding the following to .git/config :

```
[instaweb]
local = true
httpd = apache2 -f
port = 4321
modulepath = /usr/libexec/apache2
```

and running '`git instaweb`' results in :

```
apache2 not found.  
Install apache2 or use --httpd to specify another httpd daemon.
```

How should I set up `.git/config` to have it use my default web server ?

Thanks

Comment: I could not find any solution to this problem so far. The best turnaround that worked was to use another supporter server :
httpd = webrick

Comment: you should use the full path for `httpd` configuration option (to the apache binary), and on command-line the [tag:apache]-specific [`-m`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-instaweb#git-instaweb--m) option pointing to apache modules directory (eg. `/usr/local/lib/apache2`) should also be specified if different from the default (`/usr/lib/apache2/modules`).

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that apache2 is named httpd in OS X, and the modules are somewhere else. I have tried changing the configuration so that it points to the correct paths, but still the server didn't work.

Alternatively, you can use the already installed webrick daemon. Add these lines to your ~/.gitconfig file (global setting) or .git/config file (local setting) :

```
[instaweb]
               httpd = webrick
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [`git-instaweb` patch from February 2009](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/2/11/4955924), you see:

```
# check if server can be executed
httpd_only="$(echo $httpd | cut -f1 -d' ')"
if ! type $httpd_only >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo >&2 "$httpd_only not found. Install $httpd_only or use" \
           + "--httpd to specify another httpd daemon."
fi
```

Is there a problem with your apache2 executable attribute?

---

Update 2014 (5 years later): a [commit like f8ee1f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8ee1f02da6182a3242306a52c5ae7a39547b37e) shows that git-instaweb not only suports Apache, but it does support Apache 2.4:

> Detect available Apache MPMs and use first available according to following order of precedence:

- mpm_event
- mpm_prefork
- mpm_worker

[Thomas Okken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670341/thomas-okken)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22597691/6309) (upvoted) details how to reference https for starting git-instaweb.

Comment: Maybe. Apache is already running on this server. If I change 'apache2' for 'httpd', I get 'Unknown httpd specified: httpd'.

Answer (score 1):

I got git instaweb to work with the built-in Apache on my Mac (running Lion) as follows:

1. As root:

   ```
   cd /usr/sbin; ln -s httpd apache2
   ```
2. As root: edit **/usr/libexec/git-core/git-instaweb**: add the lines

   ```
   LockFile "$fqgitdir/gitweb/$httpd_only/access.lock"
   User UsernameForYourGitServer
   ```

   after the line

   ```
   PidFile "$fqgitdir/pid"
   ```
3. Finally, as your git user, cd to your repository, and run

   ```
   git instaweb --httpd apache2 -m /usr/libexec/apache2
   ```

This even works when you are already using the standard server, i.e. when you have "Web Sharing" turned on. The gitweb server will be a separate process, listening on port 1234, rather than port 80 which is used by the standard server.

To launch this server using launchd, create a file **/Library/LaunchDaemons/git-web.plist**, like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>GitWeb</string>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Wherever/Your/Repository/Is</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>git</string>
            <string>instaweb</string>
            <string>--httpd</string>
            <string>apache2</string>
            <string>-m</string>
            <string>/usr/libexec/apache2</string>
        </array>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```